POST 404 NOT FOUND when inserting new user
Im new to REACT development and i am using expressjs as my backend and mysql as my database
im currently building a login/signup. However, I kept getting stuck on this error
SignUpModal.js:19
POST http://localhost:5000/admin-signup 404 (Not Found)
when i submitted the form

this is my code for the backend
// Signup Route 
app.post('/admin-signup', async (req, res) => {
    const { username, password } = req.body;

    if (!username || !password) {
        return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Username and password are required' });
    }

    try {
        // Check if the username already exists
        const [existingUser] = await db.query('SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ?', [username]);
        if (existingUser.length > 0) {
            return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Username already exists' });
        }

        // Hash the password
        const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);

        // Insert the new user into the database
        const result = await db.query('INSERT INTO user (username, password, role) VALUES (?, ?, ?)', [username, hashedPassword, 'admin']);

        // Generate a token
        const token = jwt.sign({ id: result.insertId, username }, 'your_jwt_secret', { expiresIn: '1h' });

        res.status(201).json({ message: 'User created successfully', token });
    } catch (err) {
        console.error('Error during sign up:', err.message);
        res.status(500).json({ message: 'Internal server error' });
    }
});

and my signup Modal
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios'; // Add axios to make HTTP requests

const SignUpModal = ({ isOpen, onClose }) => {
    const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
    const [error, setError] = useState('');
    const [success, setSuccess] = useState('');

    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        // Clear previous messages
        setError('');
        setSuccess('');

        try {
            // Make POST request to the /admin-signup endpoint
            const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/admin-signup', { username, password });

            // Handle successful signup
            if (response.status === 201) {
                console.log(response.data.message); // Log the success message
                setSuccess(response.data.message);
                // Optionally, store the token in localStorage or a global state
                localStorage.setItem('token', response.data.token);
                // Optionally, you might want to redirect the user or update the UI
                onClose(); // Close the modal after successful signup
            }
        } catch (err) {
            // Improved error handling
            if (err.response) {
                // Server responded with a status other than 2xx
                setError(err.response.data.message || 'An error occurred during signup');
            } else if (err.request) {
                // The request was made but no response was received
                setError('No response received from the server');
            } else {
                // Something happened in setting up the request
                setError('Error setting up the request: ' + err.message);
            }
        }
    };


    if (!isOpen) return null;

    return (
        <div className='modal-overlay'>
            <div className='modal-content'>
                <button className='close-btn' onClick={onClose}>X</button>
                <h2>Sign Up</h2>
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                    <label>
                        Username:
                        <input
                            type='text'
                            value={username}
                            onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)}
                            required
                        />
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        Password:
                        <input
                            type='password'
                            value={password}
                            onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                            required
                        />
                    </label>
                    <button type='submit'>Sign Up</button>
                    {success && <p className='success-message'>{success}</p>}
                    {error && <p className='error-message'>{error}</p>}
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default SignUpModal;

I wanted to be able to insert user credentials to my database

are you sure the api is running in port 5000 ?

I commented on this in staging ground with requiring minor edits, including demonstrating that your code is running on the correct port. Dissapointing you didn't make an attempt at improving the question!

Sorry i did find what my error is, as react does not produce error ontop then i could not see the error.

const result = await db.query('INSERT INTO user (username, password, role) VALUES (?, ?, ?)', [username, hashedPassword, 'admin']);
on my insert statement, the role is not in my database column thus it does not show or logged as error in my console and it does trigger the 404 error
i have fixed it and remove the role and replace it with user_type
Now i could insert data to my db
